# presentViewController reloads UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController that contains a UITableView. There is a button in the UIViewController that launches a modal window (presentViewController).

For some reason, the UITableView always scrolls up to the top whenever I launch the modal window. It may be calling reloadData.

I've been messing around with ViewDidLoad, ViewWillLoad, ViewDidDisappear and ViewWillDisappear to scroll to the right position as we leave or come back. None of these seem to do the trick.

Any one experience this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: And how about [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourController animated:YES]; does it also scroll your tableView?

Comment: Give more code in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidDisapear, viewWillDisapear.

Comment: Yes, it does. And I can fix it when I come back with ViewWillAppear, but only if animated is YES. Changing it to animated:NO, makes my code in viewWillAppear useless. Very strange.